# Prepend Element

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically generate chat but the messages get inserted below the previous meaning the user has to scroll down to see a new message which isn't very good! I'm trying to change it so the message gets inserted above the last message.

```
var elementDiv = document.createElement("div");
elementDiv.className = "chat-message error";
elementDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chatBoxMessage));
//Insert message
var oldMsg = "chat-message";
document.getElementsByClassName('message-window').appendChild(elementDiv);
document.body.insertBefore(elementDiv, oldMsg);
```

The variable `chatBoxMessage` is used to define the text.

Running this throws the error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node' : parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'.
```

Comment: According to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp, you probably inversed the two arguments of insertBefore.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `oldMsg` is a string type. You'll have to call `document.createTextNode` with the oldMsg in order for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to wrap your message in a text node.

```
document.createTextNode("chat-message");
```

Your error message indicates that your text is not a valid node.

> parameter 2 is not of type 'Node'

See: [MDN - Document.createTextNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode)

```js
onReady('#message-window', function() {
  pushNewMessage('Third!');
  pushNewMessage('Second!');
  pushNewMessage('First!');
});

function pushNewMessage(chatBoxMessage) {
  var errorMessageDiv = document.createElement('div');
  errorMessageDiv.className = 'chat-message error';
  errorMessageDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(chatBoxMessage));

  //Insert message
  var messageWindow = document.getElementById('message-window');
  
  messageWindow.insertBefore(errorMessageDiv, messageWindow.firstChild);
}

// Convinience function -- Wait for element or body load...
function onReady(selector, callback, ms) {
  var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
    if ((document.querySelector(selector) || document.body) !== undefined) {
      window.clearInterval(intervalID);
      callback.call(this);
    }
  }, ms || 500);
}
```

```html
<div id="message-window">
</div>
```

Comment: I've given this a try but I get an error which says `The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.`

I guess because `message-window` is the container and I want to insert into that container the messages of which the new message will appear above the old one. These messages are not children of each other.

Comment: I gave your variables more descriptive name, try it again.

Answer (score 0):

I made a sample implementation. Hopefully this is what you are looking for:

HTML:

```
<div id='container'></div>
```

Javascript:

```
// select the container
var container = document.getElementById('container');

// create chat messages
var msg1 = createChatMsg('Chat1');
var msg2 = createChatMsg('Chat2');
var msg3 = createChatMsg('Chat3');

// Insert Messages
container.insertBefore(msg1, container.firstChild);
container.insertBefore(msg2, container.firstChild);
container.insertBefore(msg3, container.firstChild);

// create chatmessage
function createChatMsg(message) {
  var chatMsg = document.createElement('div');
  chatMsg.className = 'some-chat';
  chatMsg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(message));

  return chatMsg;
}
```

Hopefully this helps and is what you are looking for. Sample implementation: http://jsfiddle.net/f1d02e49/